# Error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Tags: php

Importo desde mi index un archivo claseticket donde tengo una consulta sql que pretende sumar los valores de cada ticket generado por el campo prioridad de una base de datos.

Archivo index.php

```
$ganancia = $ticket->CountTicketCloseEmpleado($conexion, $_SESSION['ticket_id']);
```

Archivo claseticket.php

```
function CountTicketCloseEmpleado($conexion, $id){

    $ganancia = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT SUM(prioridad)
                                         FROM ticket WHERE status = '3' AND id_usuario = ".$id." ") 
                                         or die("Error listando Ticket: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

    return $ganancia;
}
```

Al hacer echo del valor $ganancia 
tengo el siguiente error

Recoverable fatal error: 
Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Answer (score 1):

El comando de consulta de sql `mysqli_query` retorna un "objeto", por ende se asigna a $ganacia , al hacer `echo $ganancia` quieres imprimir $ganancia, que no es string y ahi nace el `Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string`. ya que $ganancia no es string.

Si quieres imprimir todo el contenido del resultado de la consulta prueba con `var_dump($ganancia)`

Técnicamente, `mysqli_query` retorna un objeto tipo `mysqli_result`

Si queremos imprimir el resultado de la suma de tu consulta podría ser algo como esto usando `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

```
function CountTicketCloseEmpleado($conexion, $id){

    if ($resultado =mysqli_query($conexión, "SELECT SUM(prioridad) as suma FROM ticket WHERE status = '3' AND id_usuario = ".$id." ")) 
    {
        $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

        echo $row['suma'];
#no olvidar hacer return

    }
}
```

Comment: me aparece esto 
object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: @JuanOrtiz si, puse el var_dump para que pudieras ver que existen datos y que con 'echo' no puedes  imprimir un dato de tipo mysqli_result,edite mi comentario para hacer más explicativo mi respuesta.

Comment: por que tengo que hacerlo con if? 
necesito una condicional para hacer una suma asi?

Comment: es un ejemplo para utilizar el echo, en el ejemplo me estoy asegurando que la consulta me traiga resultados, nada más.

Comment: entendi por que me pasa el error pero no he podido solucionar el problema con tu codigo @patovega

Comment: donde imprimes $ganancia ?

Comment: Ya que usas `if`, lo correcto es devolver siempre algo, por ejemplo `0` cuando no haya resultados. Si ignoras el `else` el usuario no sabrá nada cuando la consulta no arroje datos, tendrá la pantalla en blanco sin saber por qué. Si mandas `0` sabrá que hay `0` filas encontradas y pasará a investigar a qué se debe que no hay resultados. Hay que informar en todo momento de lo que ocurre en vez de programar código con resultados mudos en algunos casos.